# open subscheme complement of zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking at http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf example 4.5, and have a question whose answer is probably obvious:

can anyone explain how exactly $\mathbb{A}^n_R \backslash \{0\}$ is a scheme? It should be a union of ring spectra but I don't see why. I'm not sure what the given (3.6) there references.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is preferred to make questions self-contained, as opposed to just providing a link. Could you either include a picture of the question and necessary definitions etc, or, better, type the question in the body of your post? MSE uses MathJax, which is by and large "Latex markup between dollar signs".

Comment: $\mathbb{A}_R^n$ is Spec of $R[x_1,...,x_n]$. I think the problem may be that $\mathbb{A}_R^n \backslash \{0\}$ is not meant literally, but I'm not sure

Comment: I cannot open the pdf file. Please include the whole context ...

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a scheme and $p \in X$ is a closed point, then $X \setminus \{p\}$ is an open subset of $X$ and therefore may be canonically regarded as an open subscheme of $X$. If $X=\mathbb{A}^n$, then $p=(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ means the rational point with these coordinates, corresponding to the maximal ideal $(T_1-a_1,\dotsc,T_n-a_n)$.

Comment: This is exactly the problem - how do we do this canonical regarding as an open subscheme?

Comment: This is contained in every introduction to schemes. First you should convince yourself that open subsets of locally ringed spaces can be viewed as locally ringed spaces. Then specialize to schemes, the main point is that $D(f) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(A_f)$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof that the locally ringed space corresponding to an open subset $U$ of a scheme $X$ is a scheme:

Let $p$ be any point in $X$. Let $\operatorname{Spec} A$ be an affine neighborhood $V$ of $p.$ Consider the intersection of $U$ and $V.$ This will be an open set in $\operatorname{Spec} A$, and therefore contains the prime ideals not containing $x$ for some non-nilpotent $x.$ Now, $A_x$ is an affine neighborhood of $p$ in $U$, so $U$ may be written as the union of open affine sets, as desired.

In this particular case, we an write $A^n\backslash\{0\}$ as the union of $A[x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n]_{x_i}$ where $i$ ranges from 1 to $n$.